# Neo4j apoc: How to access items from AWS s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, neo4j

i try to access some s3-items (json-files) from an neo4j-database they is running in a EC2-machine.
I have some problems to understand, what is meaned with "endpoint" and "port" in the APOC-Manual.

[Screenshot from APOC Manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ij9L9.png)

I downloaded all in the picture described Plugins and my ec2 is running in a VPC.

I'm new in AWS, sorry for stupid asking :/
and thanks for your reply.

Comment: The endpoints for s3 are listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html). I guess you have to choose endpoint for your region?

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. Now i tried following cypher:

CALL apoc.load.json('s3://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:443/my-Bucket/my-key?accessKey=my-accesskey&secretKey=my-secretkey')

i still get a java unknownhost exeption with that endpoint

Comment: i Also tried different endpoints and the http-port + https-port

Comment: @Marcin Now i got it :) thanks for helping. This was exactly the answer i needed. It was another failure of mine :D. 
Now i type in the standard-endpoint of eu-central-1 with port 443 and it runs :)

Comment: Cool. I will make an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, the issue was using incorrect standard-endpoint than the required one.